# Invoking custom Jackson deserializers inside of other deserializers

Tags: serialization, spring-boot, jackson

I am writing a Spring Boot app (RESTful webservice) that uses Jackson for serialization. I have the following data models that will be sent back and forth between the service and its HTTP clients (hence these will be serialized/deserialized to/from JSON):

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    private UUID refId;

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc.
}

public abstract class BaseLookup extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;

    private String label;

    private String description;

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc.    
}

public class State extends BaseLookup {
    private String abbrev;    // "VT", "FL", etc.

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc.    
}

public class Contact extends BaseEntity {
    private String givenName;

    private String surname;

    private State state;

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc.    
}

public class Account extends BaseEntity {
    private Contact contact;

    private String code;

    // lots of other fields that will be generated server-side

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc.
}
```

Thus there will be some endpoints for CRUDding `Accounts`, others for CRUDding `Contacts`, etc. For instance, the `AccountController` will expose endpoints for CRUDding `Account` instances:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts")
public class AccountController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {
        // Do stuff and persist the account to the DB
    }
}
```

I want to simplify the JSON that HTTP clients must craft in order to create new `Account`, `Contact`, etc. instances. At the same time there are fields on those data models that I **do not want exposed** to the client-side. Things like the `BaseEntity#id` (which is the PK of the entity in the DB). Or for instance, in the case of `State`, I just want the client-side to know about (and use) the `abbrev` field, etc. I don't want them to ever see the other `BaseLookup` fields or even know about them.

Hence, my end goal is to allow the client to POST the following JSON, and have a [custom Jackson deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) convert that JSON into an `Account` instance:

```
{
  "contact" : {
    "givenName" : "Him",
    "surname" : "Himself",
    "state" : "NY"
  },
  "code" : "12345"
}
```

So you see, like I stated above, this JSON accomplishes several things:

1. The client-side doesn't provide a `BaseEntity#id` or `BaseEntity#refId` when POSTing to create a new instance
2. For the `contact.state` field, which is a `BaseLookup` with several fields (`id`, `refId`, `name`, `label`, `description`, `abbrev`), the user only has to provide the `abbrev` field, and the deserializer is expected to figure out which `State` the client is referring to
3. The `Account` class actually has many other fields that are inferred/generated server-side; the client doesn't need to know about them in order to create an `Account` instance
4. The JSON above is a simplified form of what we would get if we serialized an `Account` with Jackson's default behavior; this is to make things easier on the client-side and even more secure on the server-side (not exposing PKs, etc.)

**The important thing to note here** is that the JSON sent to this controller for the `contact` field is identical to the JSON that will be POSTed to a `ContactController` for creating new `Contact` instances.

Here's the problem:

```
public class AccountDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Account> {
    public AccountDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AccountDeserializer(Class<Account> accClazz) {
        super(accClazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Account deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext dCtx)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.codec.readTree(jsonParser)

        Contact contact = ??? // TODO: How to invoke ContactDeserializer here?

        String accountCode = node.get("code").asText();

        // Generate lots of other Account field values here...

        Account account = new Account(contact, accountCode, /* other fields here */);

        return account;
    }
}
```

Since I will also have a `ContactController` (for CRUDding `Contact` instances irrespective of an associated `Account`), and because I have similar desires to hide `Contact` fields from the client-side as well as to simplify the JSON coming into this `ContactController#createContact` endpoint, I will **also** need a `ContactDeserializer` in addition to this `AccountDeserializer`...

```
public class ContactDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Contact> {
    // ...etc.
}
```

This `ContactDeserializer` will be responsible for converting JSON into `Contact` instances. But since `Account` instances also contain `Contact` instances, and because the "contact JSON" inside the outer "account JSON" will be the same as any JSON that the client sends to any of the "contact endpoints", I'd like to invoke the `ContactDeserializer` from inside the `AccountDeserializer` somehow.

That way, when the `ContactController` receives "contact JSON" to create a new `Contact` instance, the `ContactDeserializer` is engaged to get the job done. *And*, if the `AccountController` receives "account JSON" to create a new `Account` instance, then the `AccountDeserializer` is engaged to get that job done...**and** it uses the `ContactDeserialzer` to handle the deserialization of the account JSON's internal `contact` field as well.

**Can this be done?!** Can one Jackson deserializer reuse other deserializers inside of it? If so, how? If not, then what's the solution here?!

Comment: Why not just inject `ContactDeserializer` via constructor to your `AccountDeserializer` before registering it in object mapper? If you look at Jackson source, you'll also notice that the same thing is being done throughout various implementations of `StdDeserializer`.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke `ContactDeserializer` by calling the `treeToValue` method of `ObjectCodec`. Jackson will automatically pick up the `ContactDeserializer` for you if you've registered it on your `ObjectMapper`.

```
public class AccountDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Account> {

    @Override
    public Account deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
        JsonNode contactNode = node.get("contact");

        Contact contact = null;
        if (contactNode != null) {
            contact = p.getCodec().treeToValue(contactNode, Contact.class);
        }
        return new Account(contact, /* account properties */);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to add your deserializers to existing mapper which is created by Spring Boot, you can autowire it in one of your configuration classes and customize as you like.

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
                .addDeserializer(Account.class, new AccountDeserializer())
                .addDeserializer(Contact.class, new ContactDeserializer());

        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks @Edd (+1) - but remember this is a Spring Boot app, any idea as to how I could "register" custom serializers/deserializers on the `ObjectMapper` that Spring is providing under the hood? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I updated my answer to include an example of how you could register deserializers on the existing mapper.